# Which of these drivers do I need? (RAID controller for Asus P5BW-LA)

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, raid, sata, slipstream

I've been looking for drivers for my Asus P5BW-LA motherboard (running Windows XP Pro SP3) that will allow me to use RAID and/or AHCI SATA mode instead of IDE. I found two different candidates:

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/17762/Intel-R-Matrix-Storage-Manager-V8-9-0-1023

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/17312/Intel-Matrix-Storage-Manager-for-Mobile-Boards-for-Windows-XP-and-Windows-Vista

Does anyone know which one I need? I'm guessing it's the second one since it supports Media Center Edition (which is what the PC in question was originally installed with), but I just wanted to be sure? Am I going to have to slipstream these drivers and reinstall Windows XP to properly install them? I downloaded both .exes and extracted them, but I couldn't find any .inf files in the resulting folders to use with nLite. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I think it's more likely than either of the things you found: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/18668/F6-Floppy-Disk-Utility-for-AHCI-for-Desktop-Boards

This is the utility to create a driver floppy (you're running XP, you do have a floppy drive, right?) you can use to load drivers by pressing F6 during the XP install sequence.

Intel also appears to be directing people to the OEM for AHCI drivers. See this thread: https://communities.intel.com/thread/113478

Comment: I don't have a floppy drive. And I'm not sure if I can use a USB floppy drive if I can find one.

Comment: You should be able to. XP does not support loading AHCI drivers from USB thumbdrives, but a floppy, even connected via USB should work.

Comment: I downloaded the utility from Intel to look at it. Why does the readme mention an .exe file even though there isn't one in the .zip I downloaded?

Comment: I just downloaded chipset and mass storage drivers from driverpacks.net. Can I just use nLite to create a new XP .iso, burn it to CD, and slipstream the driver (IASTOR.INF) to the PC? Do I need to install 965g.inf (chipset) as well?

Comment: Yes; You can do that.  Might want to test if the driver even solves your problem first though by using a floppy disk.

Comment: Just got the RAID controller to install by slipstreaming it! Windows XP now successfully boots from the HDD with the SATA Mode in the BIOS set to RAID! It doesn't work when I have it set to AHCI, though. And I haven't tried it with IDE mode. Thank you for the advice, however!